# calling string variable from another class

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I have the following code which works perfectly when the respective buttons are pressed by opening the screen and displaying the layout activity_gpsnetworklocation.xml.
I do not want the user to press these, but would like to get the variables from another class.
For that created static variables and I'm calling from another Class.

```
Example eLatitudeGPS = gpsnetworklocation.getLatGPS();
```

I am getting null values from both emulator and physical devices. Can anyone help resolve this?

```
package com.test.myapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class gpsnetworklocation extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView txtViewLatGPS;
private TextView txtViewLongGPS;
private TextView txtViewAltGPS;

private TextView txtViewLatNetwork;
private TextView txtViewLongNetwork;
private TextView txtViewAltNetwork;

public static String LatGPS;
public static String LongGPS;
public static String AltGPS;
public static String LatNetwork;
public static String LongNetwork;
public static String AltNetwork;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

private LocationManager mLocationManagerGPS;
private LocationListener mLocationListenerGPS;

private LocationManager mLocationManagerNetwork;
private LocationListener mLocationListenerNetwork;

private Button btnGPS;
private Button btnNetwork;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpsnetworklocation);

    txtViewLatGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewLatGPS);
    txtViewLongGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewLonGPS);
    txtViewAltGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewAltGPS);

    txtViewLatNetwork = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewLatNetwork);
    txtViewLongNetwork = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewLonNetwork);
    txtViewAltNetwork = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewAltNetwork);

    btnGPS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGPSLoc);
    btnNetwork = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNetworkLoc);

    //get data from Network and then from GPS
    getPositionNetwork();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Display responses from Google
            getPositionGPS();
        }
    }, 6000);

    btnGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getPositionGPS();
        }
    });

    btnNetwork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getPositionNetwork();
        }
    });
}

private void getPositionGPS() {
    mLocationManagerGPS = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            txtViewLatGPS.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            txtViewLongGPS.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
            txtViewAltGPS.setText(Double.toString(location.getAltitude()));
            LatGPS = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            LongGPS = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            showAlert(R.string.GPS_disabled);
        }
    };

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestLocationPermission();
        } else {
            btnGPS.setEnabled(false);
            mLocationManagerGPS.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5, 0, mLocationListenerGPS);
        }
    }
}

private void getPositionNetwork() {
    mLocationManagerNetwork = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            txtViewLatNetwork.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            txtViewLongNetwork.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
            txtViewAltNetwork.setText(Double.toString(location.getAltitude()));
            LatNetwork = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            LongNetwork = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            showAlert(R.string.Network_disabled);
        }
    };

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestLocationPermission();
        } else {
            btnNetwork.setEnabled(false);
            mLocationManagerNetwork.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5, 0, mLocationListenerNetwork);
        }
    }
}

private void showAlert(int messageId) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(messageId).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void requestLocationPermission() {
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.GPS_permissions).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(gpsnetworklocation.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
        }).show();
    } else {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.GPS_permissions).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_watch_permissions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName())));
            }
        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mLocationManagerGPS != null) {
        mLocationManagerGPS.removeUpdates(mLocationListenerGPS);
    }

    if (mLocationManagerNetwork != null) {
        mLocationManagerNetwork.removeUpdates(mLocationListenerNetwork);
    }

    txtViewLatGPS.setText(null);
    txtViewLongGPS.setText(null);
    txtViewAltGPS.setText(null);

    txtViewLatNetwork.setText(null);
    txtViewLongNetwork.setText(null);
    txtViewAltNetwork.setText(null);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!btnGPS.isEnabled()) {
        btnGPS.setEnabled(true);
    }

    if (!btnNetwork.isEnabled()) {
        btnNetwork.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
//provide variables for other processes
public static String getLatGPS() { return LatGPS;}
public static String getLongGPS() { return LongGPS;}
public static String getAltGPS() { return AltGPS;}
public static String getLatNetwork() { return LatNetwork;}
public static String getLongNetwork() { return LongNetwork;}
public static String getAltNetwork() { return AltNetwork;}
}
```

Comment: For which variable you are getting NULL values?

Comment: for LatGPS, LongGPS, LatNetwork and LongNetwork.

Comment: Read about service and broadcast reciever

Answer (score 0):

while doing the way you did it you are'nt going through the Activity **lifecycle methods**
so actually you're not running **gpsnetworklocation** you are just creating and instance of the class and no method except **getLatGPS** is triggered and of course the values will be null (they didnt Initialized).

As that said..
something in your architecure isn't correct - try using an **active** Activity/Fragment to get the relevant GPS location and then fetch it from there.

Hope it helps , Good Luck.

Comment: Can you please suggest how do I do that? - active Activity/Fragment

Comment: where does "Example eLatitudeGPS = gpsnetworklocation.getLatGPS()" happend?

Comment: I'm calling it from another Activity in OnCreate section

Comment: so use above code inside that Activity or use a custom Manager class to make it global for entire App
remember when you're attempt to use code inside activity - that activity should be active (Loaded with **startActivity** method) or you wont be able to use that code..